# php serialize empty associative array

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array, empty-list

I want to dump an associative array to file with php. Sometimes the result can be empty and in this case I want the content of the file be exactly : { } so that I can process all files in the same way. However I can only initialize a simple array in php and so the output in the file is always this : [ ]. I already tried adding a dummy entry to the associative array and then deleting the entry again so that the array is empty, but then again [ ] is the output in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast it to object before encoding:

```
json_encode((object) $array);
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) function has an option that will coerce arrays into objects where ever contextually appropriate - ***i.e.*** associative arrays but this also includes empty arrays, for example:

```php
$array = array(
    'foo' => array(),
    'bar' => array()
);

echo json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);  // {"foo":{},"bar":{}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another answer to this is to use `ArrayObject` instead of `[]` when initialising the variable.

The following illustrates the problem. When the associative array is empty, it is JSON encoded as `'[]'`:

```php
$object = [];
echo json_encode($object); // you get '[]'

$object['hello'] = 'world';
echo json_encode($object); // you get '{hello: "world"}'
```

Instead, keep everything the same, but when you declare the `$object`, use `ArrayObject`:

```php
$object = new ArrayObject;
echo json_encode($object); // you get '{}'

$object['hello'] = 'world';
echo json_encode($object); // you get '{hello: "world"}'
```

The reason this is a good alternative is because using `(object) []` converts the variable to an stdClass meaning you have to access the properties using `$variable->property`. However, if all your existing code was written using `$variable['property']`, then using `(object) []` means you will have to change all of that code, when you can instead just use `new ArrayObject`.

Link to [ArrayObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) that has been available since PHP5

Answer (score 1):

Your going to have to check if the array is empty.

```
if (empty($array_to_dump)) {
    print ':{}';
} else {
    print serialize($array_to_dump);
}
```

However, the array you get back when you unserialize should be exactly the same either way... an empty array.

Edit: or use the above, even better.